# TextPad "find in files" not matching on simple OR regex

Tags: regex, textpad

I've tried searching files for either/or word scenarios and they always fail to find any results in TextPad.

An example is trying to find something like `summer|winter` where I want to return any files that contain either the word "summer" or the word "winter".

[image]

This regex works fine in other programs like Notepad++. Why doesn't it work in TextPad?

Comment: Haven't used it in years,but assuming you turned on the regex search option maybe textpad wants you to write the parens `(summer|winter)` or i've seen this in some apps `\(summer|winter\)` which is non-obvious cause you woud think you don't want to escape but it requires you to.

Comment: @gillyspy No luck. I get zero results with those too.

Comment: their online faq says that they fixed "Reject "|" as a regular expression" in 7.0.7

Comment: @gillyspy Thanks! I'm using an older version so that must be the issue. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Textpad.com online release notes**](http://textpad.com/support/relnotes.html#v707) says that they fixed a bug in 7.0.7 related to this where they:

> Reject "|" as a regular expression

Answer (score 1):

Textpad seems to use slightly unusual syntax for regex 'finds'. Read the TextPad help file for the details. Here is an example for finding a IPv4 number. It works with textpad v4.7.3 'Find' and 'Find in files'

```
[^0-9][0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}[^0-9]
```

Answer (score 1):

On older versions It works with:  `\(summer\|winter\),`

Escape (alt+92 backslash) before every paren and "or" carácter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using Textpad 6.x, I have to escape the or operator and it works:

summer\|winter

Answer (score -1):

Try (summer)|(winter): it could be reading it as summe(r|w)inter.