# Using TextPad to search for multiple strings containing vertical bars

Tags: find, textpad

all. I'm using TextPad and I am having difficulty finding answers on how to search for multiple expressions that each contain the vertical bar character.

Specifically, what I would like to do is search multiple documents for any of the following four strings. *Note: The strings I want to search for are not bolded.*

**String 1.** word1 |

**String 2.** | word1

**String 3.** word2 |

**String 4.** | word2

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regex to find multiple expressions that have a common pattern. Use find in files to do this across multiple files. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16365795/textpad-find-in-files-not-matching-on-simple-or-regex) is another thread that I believe has what you're looking for.